# eclipse highlight on string literals

Tags: html, sql, string, eclipse

I'm new on Eclipse and see some need that other IDE/text editor has and I don't find in Eclipse.

One of that is highlight string literal. When write some literal string that contents is SQL or HTML code Eclipse don't recognize that and show a simple string literal highlight.

I want (if have) some away to highlight thats string code. If is possible, syntax validation too. Can one help me?

For example:

Sublime Text

[image: Some SQL string in Sublime]

Eclipse

[image: Some SQL string in Eclipse]

Comment: are you trying to write HTML or CSS or SQL in eclipse ?

Comment: Basically both. Some HTML and SQL code on my PHP project.

Comment: So you need steps now to write your html,php,sql in eclipse right ?

Comment: well, I need that my strings highlighted, like the images. If is possible syntax validation too.